# How could I apply wanted conditions with "if_else" in this case

Tags: r

I am working in a dataset with mosses and liverwort sampled along an altitudinal gradient. 11 altitudes were sampled between 350m and 2750m, each 200m of interval.

The range of a species is defined as altitudes between minimum and maximum altitudes where the species was recorded. In my reflection I supposed that species which was recorded between 2 different altitudes was also present between those 2 altitudes.

To test that, I am looking to find the species recorded at the limits of the observed range but not between. If a species is present in certain altitude between the limits of the range, but not each, it's not a problem, I'm only looking for the species that are absent in each altitude between the maximum and the minimum one. To illustrate that, in my output, AEROSUBPM will be the only species to be selected, not ANASAURI.

I hope I was enough clear in my explanation. Here is an output of presence/absence data, with only 2 variables, the species names, and the altitudes.

```
> PA_brk%>%
+   dplyr::select(1:6)%>%
+   slice(1:10)%>%
+   dput()
structure(list(alti = c(350, 550, 750, 950, 1150, 1350, 1550, 
1750, 1950, 2150), ACROEMER = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), ACROMEGA = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), AEROSUBPM = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AMAZDIPL = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), ANASAURI = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I guess there is a way to do what I want by using conditions as "if_else" but I tried and I am really lost in my reflection, that's why some help would be really helpfull.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what the question is. You record 1==presence and 0==non presence for a species? And then you only care about the boundaries - ie. the maximum and minimum altitude a species is seen. If what I am saying is correct, convert your dataset to long format with two columns: Altitude and Species. Then using pipes '%>%' create a min_altitute and max_altitude for each group of the species column (i.e. where you see the first and last 1 in your dataset.

Comment: Also, don't know how common it is in your domain visualising things but you should use a lolipop chart to present the data. https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/lollipop_basic.html

Comment: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/303-lollipop-plot-with-2-values.html

Comment: I'm having trouble to be clear with what I want, sorry about that.

I would like to know which species were not found (0 for absence) between their minimum and maximum boundaries (1 for presence). 

In the subset of data that I gave as exemple, AEROSUBPM will be the only species that I'm looking for. Because this species wasn't found in any altitudes between is boundaries (only 1 altitude in this case). ANASAURI wouldn't be selected, because this species is present at 1 altitude between is boundaries. 

How I could select those species in this subset ? to do it so in my dataset

Comment: What is minimum and maximum boundary? If it is 350 and 2150 in your data then all the species are 0 there then why do you want output as only `AEROSUBPM` ?

Comment: The boundary of AEROSUBPM are 550m and 950m. Because this species isn't present (0) at 750m, the only altitude in this exemple between the boundary, but it could have been more of an altitude, AEROSUBPM will be in the output. For ANASAURI, is boundary are 750 and 1950m but because the species is present in atleast 1 altitude between the boundary (here 1550m) she wont appear in the output.  I hope I'm clear enough now, thank you for your help